# Amazon S3 Extended Request ID null

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to Amazon bucket using S3 service. Getting below exception when connecting through company's "proxy server".

```
<code>        
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
    uploadLocation.getAccessKeyId(), uploadLocation.getSecretAccessKey(), uploadLocation.getSessionToken());


    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfiguration.setProxyHost(proxyAddress); 
    clientConfiguration.setProxyPort(Integer.parseInt(proxyPort));
    clientConfiguration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);

    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                        .withCredentials(new  AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                        .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
                        .withRegion("us-east-1")
                        .build();

    PutObjectResult putObjectResult = s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(uploadLocation.getBucket(), 
                        uploadLocation.getObject_key(), file));



Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1592)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1029)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:741)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:665)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:647)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:511)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4227)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4174)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1722)


</code>
```

Please note that it works perfectly when proxy is not used and hence ClientConfiguration object is not required.

Don't have much visibility into S3 bucket configuration as a different vendor company is using Amazon S3 as their storage system.
Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Just in case if some one faces the same problem, the issue was resolved by open whitelisting upload URL. Make sure all URLs are whitelisted in proxy as the error message is obscure.